# Different types even though same value assigned

Tags: rust

I am having hard time wrapping my head around types and references in rust. For eg., I have this code:

```
let my_arr = [3, 5, 4, 88, 77];
let my_slice1 = &my_arr;
let my_slice2: &[i32] = &my_arr;
```

IDE suggests my_slice1 is of type &[i32, 5] ie reference type to array of type [i32, 5].

If this suggestion is correct, then my_slice1 and my_slice2 are of different types even though they have been assigned same value(&my_arr).

Is some implicit conversion happening for my_slice2?

Comment: Yes. It's called an unsized cast, or unsized coercion, and it converts arrays to slices (amongst other things).

Comment: Ok, so going by basic rust rules, &my_arr is a reference to an array, but it can be type cast to &[i32] also.

Comment: But &my_arr is not an array, its a reference to an array.

Comment: Yes, it converts references to arrays to references to slices.